# PHP I want an own cache system (output buffer)

Tags: php, caching, buffer

According to GET parameters, I want to save the output HTML and save to my own cache. Next time it's called, load the cache. It sounds easy to use `ob_start()` and `ob_get_contents()` but what if the other running scripts in between use this too? It spoils the "original" output buffering, right?

How to globally save the output?

Comment: don't put in cache whole page, cache only data, which should be fetched from database.

Comment: don't cache only data, cache the whole page. ;D

Comment: I'm with Jens on this: Cache the whole page. Reading stuff from the database is just as fast as reading it from a file. Just remember "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things" (Phil Karlton). So be sure you know when to rewrite the cache file(s)

Comment: @Flambino `Reading stuff from the database is just as fast as reading it from a file.` - you just noob. Nothing personal. And caching in files is almost most stupid kind of caching.

Comment: @OZ_: could you explain more? Caching an entire PHP page instead of re-processing it each time doesn't make sense to you? Even if the PHP file does not access the DB?

Answer (score 2):

To quote the [PHP manual for ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

> Output buffers are stackable, that is, you may call `ob_start()` while
>   another `ob_start()` is active. Just make sure that you call
>   `ob_end_flush()` the appropriate number of times.

In other words: No, it doesn't spoil the original output buffering; buffering can be nested. You can also use `ob_get_flush()` instead of `ob_end_flush()` to "stop" buffering.